# how can I turn off screen in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to turn off the screen. So I tried to do it with PowerManager class but it didn't turn off screen.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
wl.acquire();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock or turn off the screen programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44679868/lock-or-turn-off-the-screen-programmatically)

Comment: Have you added the permission for accessing wake lock?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off screen by overriding system screen turn off time.

First get system turn off time

```
int defaultTurnOffTime =  Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

then put your turn off time

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

and when the screen turned off, set default turn off time

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, defaultTurnOffTime);
```

add below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: Thakns, but the app is crashing. 
java.lang.SecurityException: com.detect.bait was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question if you've tried this, but you might need to make sure that you have the  in your manifest:

> Any application using a WakeLock must request the android.permission.WAKE_LOCK permission in an  element of the application's manifest.

Another area that you might look is logcat to see if there is any stack traces or errors being logged, which could provide more context for people to help out.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already set that permission, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[@SuperDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7161329/superdev), add the following to your Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

This will resolve your app crash.

Hope it helps :)